# Numero maximo de una tabla

Tags: java, array, funciones

sigo realizando pruebas, esta vez he intentado crear un programa que me localice el numero más grande de una tabla.
El programa está planteado con funciones y la tabla se rellena aleatoriamente, este es el codigo:

```
package recursividad;

import java.util.*;

public class maxTabla {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int max;
        int t[];
        t = new int[6];
        max = max(t);

        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Programa que localiza el numero mayor en una tabla");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            t[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);

        }
        System.out.println("La tabla es: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(t[i]);

        }

        System.out.println("El numero mas grande es: " + max);
    }

    public static int max(int t[]) {
        int max;

        max = t[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            if (t[i] > max) {
                max = t[i];
            }
        }

        return max;

    }
}
```

El problema es que siempre me dice que el valor máximo es "0"
Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es muy simple. Siempre te dice que el valor máximo es 0 porque estás llamando a la función `max()` antes de tener cualquier numero dentro de la tabla.

```
max=max(t);
...
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
     t[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
}
```

Pon esa llamada después de rellanar la tabla:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    t[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
}
max = max(t);
```

**Output:**

```
------------------------------------------------------
Programa que localiza el numero mayor en una tabla
------------------------------------------------------
La tabla es: 
8
22
82
56
90
85
El numero mas grande es: 90
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Revisé el codigo y lo vi.
Estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta y los ejercicios los "invento" entonces no tengo forma ver la correción. Gracias, amigo Mario

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido :)

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que ejecutas la función antes de rellenar la tabla. Pon la llamada a la función `max=max(t);` después de rellenar la tabla con números.

```
package recursividad;

import java.util.*;

public class maxTabla {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int max;
    int t[];
    t = new int[6];
    

    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Programa que localiza el numero mayor en una tabla");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        t[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);

    }

    max = max(t);
    System.out.println("La tabla es: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(t[i]);

    }

    System.out.println("El numero mas grande es: " + max);
}

public static int max(int t[]) {
    int max;

    max = t[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        if (t[i] > max) {
            max = t[i];
        }
    }

    return max;

}
```

Comment: Para que esto sea una respuesta válida, debes agregarlas modificaciones necesarias. No solo decirlas, al decirlas es más un comentario. Es correcto si, pero vago, si lo completas, tu respuesta será completa.

Comment: Considero que en este caso no era necesario volver a poner el código porque la solución era bastante fácil y quedaba completamente determinada con el texto. Pero bueno, ya está hecho.

Comment: Aunque sea fácil y obvio, la respuesta debe ser completa ;) Y gracias por agregarla